# C++x11 program compiles and run but shows errors/warnings on eclipse

Tags: c++, eclipse, macos, c++11, installation

I'm trying to work with C++11 on my eclipse (using mac); I have upgraded the gcc to 4.7 and wrote the simple code in the picture below. As you can see, there's a red line below the

```
thread t1(call_from_thread);
t1.join();
```

and there's a worrning message (yellow) under the

```
#include <thread>
```

This compiles and run despite the errors/warning. I'd like to know why do I still get those errors?

Note:

1. My settings on the Cross G++ compiler's and Linker's command is: /opt/local/bin/g++
2. I'm writing this after reading http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/mv/msg/282618/787571/ and trying to circumvent this issue with **GXX_EXPERIMENTAL_CXX0X** I'm still with the same error message
3. I also tried on both juno and Indigo

Thanks

[image]

Comment: @mfontanini yep, I've already performed those steps with multiple combinations and so forth - still I get the same notorious error (at leaset, at this stage, I'm able to compile it).

Comment: @Ail, thanks - that did the trick. (let me vent) I spent hours to get this - why eclipse cant make it so easy) Rrrr. Thanks again